# The login form is not showing if I used isset

Tags: php, forms, session

I am not sure what is going on here but my login button does not show up if I used the following code:

But it does work if I removed the isset... I guess that I don't need to use isset for a login page because it is not sending any information?

I tried to use the same code but without the isset function and it works but most videos are using the isset function

```
<?php
include_once 'navbar.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION{'u_uid'})) {
echo '<div class="login_form">
         <div class="login_form_welcome">
            <h2>Welcome to the Login Form</h2>
          </div>
          <form action="medical_login_process.php" method="POST">
           <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username/email">
           <br />
           <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
            <br />
           <br />
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
       </div>';

   } else {
echo '  <div class="logout">
         <form action="medical_logout_process.php" method="POST">
           <button type="submit" name="logout">Logout</button>
      </div>';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(isset($_SESSION{'u_uid'})) {` to `if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {`.

Note the use of square brackets instead of curly ones.

Just a heads up: I am voting to close this since it's a typo and isn't really of use to anyone but you.

Comment: And maybe a `!` before isset, cause OP is currently displaying login form if user id is already set, should be the opposite I guess.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder where the "1 bug per 20 lines of code" rule comes from. Case in point, I guess. Useful tip!

Comment: I changed it but it still doesn't show the login form for some strange reason

Comment: when I changed it to this code: I get an undefined index of u_uid but I did set this correctly in my login page

Comment: if($_SESSION['u_uid']) {